# Converting an OR to UNION in a correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

In most cases, when I'm trying to optimize an OR condition, I'm trying to see how the UNION alternative will perform. In many cases, the UNION alternative performs better, as it can be indexed properly, while the OR condition can't.

Let's assume the following example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    posts.id = (SELECT 
            postid
        FROM
            comments
        WHERE
            comments.postid = posts.id
                AND (comments.userid = 5 OR comments.score = 8)
        ORDER BY postid
        LIMIT 1);
```

In this case, transforming the subquery to a UNION clause isn't trivial, as doing so will make us wrap the entire UNION clause with another subquery, to make sure the order of the results won't be affected.
But, when applying that wrapping, we now have a 3-level nested query, instead of a 2-level query, so the table posts isn't available anymore for the UNION's internal SELECT queries, which makes the syntax invalid.

This is the transformation I was looking for and hoped will work:

```
SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        posts 
    WHERE
        posts.id = (
            SELECT
                * 
            FROM
                ((SELECT
                    comments.postid,
                    comments.postid 
                FROM
                    comments 
                WHERE
                    comments.postid = posts.id 
                    AND (
                        comments.score = 8
                    ) 
                ORDER BY
                    comments.postid LIMIT 1) 
            UNION
            DISTINCT (SELECT
                comments.postid,
                comments.postid 
            FROM
                comments 
            WHERE
                comments.postid = posts.id 
                AND (comments.userid = 5) 
            ORDER BY
                comments.postid LIMIT 1)
        ) AS union1 
    ORDER BY
        union1.postid LIMIT 1)
```

So, in this case, MySQL will just return this error: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'where clause'`.

Is there a creative way to transform this OR condition to a UNION in such correlated subqueries?

Important: I'm fully aware that this query can be re-written differently, without the original subquery, which might make this whole question irrelevant. But, for the sake of this discussion, I'm trying to see what is the best way to perform the transformation I'm after, with minimum changes.

Comment: . . Either you are trying to optimize performance *or*  you are just playing with subqueries.  If you want to optimize performance, I would suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, are you saying there is no way to do what I want, and that the only way is to approach this (and improve the performance) in a different way?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are after here, but i think the error you described is being caused by this: WHERE
        posts.id = (
            SELECT
                * 
            FROM
                ((SELECT...  you are asking posts.id to = a list instead of a value

Comment: To add to what @DanielMarcus is saying, [1] posts.id can never equal (comments.postid,comments.postid) _I have no idea why you would double-up the fields selected_, (2) the union makes it so MySQL cannot guarantee a single result, making `=` an invalid operator (_you would use `IN` instead_).

Comment: @Uueerdo, the UNION won't double it, as the goal is to ORDER and LIMIT before the subquery ends (apply that on the UNION's result as well, and not only on the internal selects).

Comment: By "double-up" I meant selecting the id field twice in each query; while you may know the union cannot produce more than one result, MySQL does not, so you might have to wrap the union with a select .. .limit 1.

Comment: In a modern database, you could do this via an APPLY or lateral join. MySql doesn't support those.

Comment: @TomShir . . . I'm saying that either you want to optimize the query or not.  If so, you should ask another question, because you have put too many constraints on this one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - my goal is to learn about these potential limitations to the fullest, and not optimize this specific query. Learning about these limitations and how to overcome them will allow me to better optimize future queries, or maybe decide to write them differently. Removed the tag of `sqlperformance` to avoid confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As with most correlated subqueries (in my experience), this seems if it would be better written as not correlated, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE posts.id IN (
        SELECT postid
        FROM comments
        WHERE comments.userid = 5 OR comments.score = 8
   )
;
```

or at very least, as an exists

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM comments AS c 
   WHERE c.postid = posts.id
      AND (c.userid = 5 OR c.score = 8)
  )
;
```

While this doesn't address the OR to UNION conversion directly, their conversions are much simpler.

---

Conversions:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE posts.id IN (
        SELECT postid
        FROM comments
        WHERE comments.userid = 5
        UNION 
        SELECT postid
        FROM comments
        WHERE comments.score = 8
   )
;
```

technically, the conversion on the second one does not need/use a UNION, but it does double the correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM comments AS c 
   WHERE c.postid = posts.id
      AND c.userid = 5
  )
OR EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM comments AS c 
   WHERE c.postid = posts.id
      AND c.score = 8
  )
;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the OR condition can't be indexed in these examples as well.. The whole goal was to convert the OR to UNION, to allow MySQL to use the indexes on `userid` and `score`.

Comment: No, OR cannot be indexed, but (1) the non-correlated version may enough performance gains you don't have to worry, (2) they are much easier to convert.

Comment: thanks for the conversions, but what about the ORDER BY part? Once you want to add that, you'll need to wrap those EXISTS queries in another subquery, which gets you to the original problem that posts will not be in scope of those internal selects anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure correlated subqueries work the way you expect them to, as your queries' ORDER BY clauses were pointless. A correlated subquery is executed separately for each row it is correlated with. _Your subqueries were ordering result sets by postid when those result sets only had a single postid._

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a `join`?

Start from here:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM  posts p
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.postid = posts.id
WHERE c.userid = 5 or c.score = 8
ORDER p.id
LIMIT 1;
```

I dare you to find a situation where that produces different results, and it's already probably quite a bit faster than what was posted.

Once you have that, you can UNION as normal:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT  p.id
    FROM  posts p
    INNER JOIN comments c ON c.postid = posts.id
    WHERE c.userid = 5 

    UNION

    SELECT  p.id
    FROM  posts p
    INNER JOIN comments c ON c.postid = posts.id
    WHERE c.score = 8
)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  p.*
    FROM  posts p
    INNER JOIN comments c ON c.postid = posts.id
    WHERE c.userid = 5 

    UNION

    SELECT  p.*
    FROM  posts p
    INNER JOIN comments c ON c.postid = posts.id
    WHERE c.score = 8
) t
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

And the first option can be even simpler, with no need for even the joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT  c.postid
    FROM  comments c
    WHERE c.userid = 5 

    UNION

    SELECT  c.postid
    FROM  comments c
    WHERE c.score = 8
)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Problem with all those is that they only get the first post, the original query was only using LIMIT to basically simulate `EXISTS`.

Comment: @Uueerdo If the `posts` table has an `id` column this is not the primary key, they have other problems.

Comment: Not suggesting such a thing; only that the original query was getting all posts that had comments by user 5 or a score of 8; not just the first such post.